# Ignoring non integers in an unknown length of data input

Tags: char, integer, scanf

i am new to c language and seeking help in understanding my mistake.
I want to write a program that counts the number of 2 digit numbers in a row of integers and chars, for example " 21c sdhhj 32 fhddhf234 45" here are 3 two digit numbers. I set terminations to my loop (failed scanf %d or EOF) and still get an infinite loop. I understand thet failed scanf of integers should return 0 or -1 at EOF so why i get infinite loop? Thank you in advance! :)

```
void read(int blue[],int red[],int couple[])
{
int vote=0,rcount=0,bcount=0;
int ok=-2;
while (ok!=EOF)
{
    ok=scanf("%d",&vote);
    if (ok==0)
        continue;
    if (vote<TOTAL&&vote>0)
    {
        rcount=vote%10;
        bcount=vote/10;
        if (rcount==bcount)
            continue;
        couple[vote]++;
        red[rcount]++;
        blue[bcount]++;
    }
    ok=0;
}
```

i want to scan and store them as long as they are smaller then TOTAL (99) until the input is over.

Comment: Learn how to debug your own code and look at all values when doing so.

Comment: Great answer thank you so much.. I'm new and learning every day step by step, if you don't want to help some one at his start at least don't answer like you did.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/CS-Wiki/wiki/C-and-Cpp-Debugging-in-VS-Code) you find instructions to debug a C program in VSCode. When debugging your program you can understand the program flow better and cope with your infinite loop.